# Does String have any internal mechanism to check existence of object in String constant pool?

Tags: java

I know that When i do below:
String s = "abc";

JVM checks for the "abc" object on string constant pool and if not present, it will create the object and its reference will be returned to s variable.

But here i want to get clear one thing that Do String have any internal mechanism to check existence of such object.

Answer (score 1):

> JVM checks for the "abc" object on string constant pool and if not present, it will create the object and its reference will be returned to s variable.

Wrong. Any string literal *is* in the constant pool, placed there by the compiler and classloader.

> But here i want to get clear one thing that Do String have any internal mechanism to check existence of such object.

It has an *external* mechanism: `String.intern().` But that has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) which the Javadoc says (in part) *returns a canonical representation for the string object.*

```
String s = new String("abc").intern();
```

Or,

```
String s = "abc".intern();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do String have any internal mechanism to check existence of such object.

Internally ... obviously yes, because otherwise `intern()` would not work.

But this functionality is within the JVM native implementation of `intern` etcetera, and is not exposed in any public java APIs.

I would argue that `String.intern()` is not a valid test.  Sure, if you call `intern` on a string and that string object is already in the pool, then you will get the same string object back.  But that doesn't give you an answer in the case where your string object isn't in the pool.  In that case, you can't tell whether the result string was in the pool before your call ... or not.  In the latter case, you have added a string to the pool *as a side-effect* of the `intern()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test to test the above feature

```
    String one="abc";
    String two="abc";
    System.out.println(one==two);
```

Output  is

```
    true
```

Which implies both variables one and two are referencing the same object address.